# How to check if there is space available before inflating a new view in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I have a fragment at the bottom of my Activity which can be filled with words(views). 
This is a image of the fragment: 
[image]

Between the blue buttons you can inflate views by clicking on a item in an GridView that is above this fragment. Everytime I click an item a view with text: "Test" is being added. It starts left with inflating views untill it doesn't fit in the LinearLayout anymore.

When the LinearLayout is full, it looks like this:[image]

When the layout looks full, you still can inflate views but you don't see them being added anymore. 
The most right purple view you can see on the image above has a bigger height then the rest because it doesn't fit anymore.

I want to check if there is enough space in the LinearLayout to inflate a new view.
This is the code that inflates the views in the LinearLayout:

```
public void inflateAllViews(){
    LayoutInflater inflaterr = (LayoutInflater) MainApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    linearLayout.removeAllViews();

    ArrayList<WordTile> wordsToInflate = WordManager.getWordsToInflate();
    for(WordTile WordTile : wordsToInflate){
        View word = inflaterr.inflate(R.layout.word, null);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)word.findViewById(R.id.text_word);
        textView.setText(WordTile.getTitle());

        linearLayout.addView(word);
    }
}
```

But I need to check whether the view can be added or not because there is no space left. Because in the background you can add unlimited views to the LinearLayout.

I tried to find a way to calculate the widths of the inflated views. The only thing I found was this:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = word.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Log.d("TEST", "Height = " + word.getHeight() + " Width = " + word.getWidth());
                widthOfChildren += word.getWidth();
                System.out.println("widthofchildren:" + widthOfChildren);
                ViewTreeObserver obs = word.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

The code works and prints the width I need for every view. But I can't use the width outside of the OnGlobalLayoutListener....

Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

EDIT:

The problem is not the width of the LinearLayout because I know that width, it is the widths of the views that are in the LinearLayout. The LinearLayout has a standard width which doesn't change.